# Recover unsaved macros (VBA PowerPoint)

Tags: vba, powerpoint, recover

It's VERY FRUSTRATING when PowerPoint crashes, because I lose all my vba codes (macros) and only the PowerPoint changes may have a backup.
It happens many times, and I have to write the codes over and over, I know why it crashes, but there's no way to fix it (only if I save the presentation manually over and over).

So I want to know how I can recover the lost macros from vba PowerPoint.

Comment: Why don't you want to save the presentation over and over manually?  That should be SOP.  You should practice the keyboard shortcut (ctrl-s) until it becomes second nature and do it all the time.

Comment: A guess:  If you haven't saved the presentation as a PPTM at least once, PowerPoint's crash recovery may save only a PPTX, which can't contain macros, so your code would be lost in the event of a crash. Try saving once as PPTM before you add any code to the project.  In any case, once having saved the presentation containing the code, all you need to do is hit CTRL+S every so often (even in the VBA editor) to save the project, code and all.  ESPECIALLY when working with tricky code that tends to crash PPT, this is just common sense.

Answer (score 0):

Periodically export and save the code modules.  You can either right click on each module and choose Export to do it manually or write some code to automatically export them.  Then when PowerPoint crashes, you can just import your saved code modules to get your code back.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I'm editing the macros, and it crashes bacause of the macros.

Comment: You can copy the text of the entire code module the same way you would a Word document: Ctrl-A to select everything, Ctrl-C to copy it to the clipboard, then go to a Word document or something and paste it there.

Answer (score 0):

J. Garth and Steve are spot on. **Ctrl+S** must become second nature to anyone coding in on Office hosted environment because you will always be on the receiving end of crashes. Especially do it before running any code. To the other point J. Garth mentions, I have a developer module I add to complex projects that allows me to save all forms, modules and classes to a timestamped sub folder below my main project folder. That's the ultimate backup strategy.